# Python: Extract parts of a string somehow got pushed down to a new line

Tags: python, string, partition

I use this code to extract the part after the final "/" of an html. I want to have that partition right after the link itself, separated by a comma. However, in the output file, the partition always got pushed down to a new line, not continuously attached to the associated link line.

```
 with open('links_parts.txt', mode='wt') as outfile:
   for link in file_to_set('links.txt'):
     path_parts = link.rpartition('/')[2]
     outfile.write(link + ','+ path_parts + '\n')
```

Comment: Try printing your variables... maybe it'll give you a clue on what's going on and how to proceed...

Comment: what returns `file_to_set` ?

Comment: try running `strip()` on your text strings. [Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm)

Comment: I tried strip() but it didn't work.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I figured out the problem. The strip() must be done before I do partition. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `link` is a line and therefore has a trailing new line character which you need to strip using `str.rstrip`:

```
for link in file_to_set('links.txt'):
    link = link.rstrip()
    path_parts = link.rpartition('/')[2]
    outfile.write(link + ',' + path_parts + '\n')
```